# Autostart apps in different desktops in openbox

Tags: window, autostart, openbox

I would like to start many GUI apps within openbox, so every window was fullscreen in different desktop. Is there possibility to run app in specific desktop in openbox? or any other idea how to write openbox autostart so its starts apps in different desktops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look in your openbox configuration, which is in the file `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml`. You can specify the settings for a window.

http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Applications

Comment: I know this solution, but it is not sufficient for me because I need to dynamically start multiple apps in startup script. And names will change probably (or they could be the same too).

Comment: So maybe you should take a look at "wmctrl".

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the DISPLAY environment variable to do this (see output of `printenv DISPLAY`) - something like

```
env DISPLAY=:0 application-name
```

and then adjust for other applications...